# Pagination displaying elements as block - CSS Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, filter, pagination, firebug

I am trying to implement a pagination with my content and allow the user to filter out results.

Here is what I have created: [Click Here](http://jsbin.com/exisi)

**The Problem:**
When filtering out content, for example taking out the colors black and green should display 4 results in total. However when doing this the pagination numbers do not update do to a CSS problem im guessing since those 4 results should display on the first page, instead they are on 3 pages.

Looking at the HTML using Firebug, you can clearly see whats happening. I set the pagination to show 5 site names per page. So when filtering out the results it hides the content but the pagination still displays them as a 'block' which is why the pagination is still displaying on 3 pages as opposed to 1 (when unchecking the the colors black and green).

I having been trying to fix this for some time now and can't figure out a solution, so I'm hoping someone can help me with this problem.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Would having the same id names for the content I want filtered have anything to do with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following should do the trick ..
let me pinpoint some things i have altered ..

1. very important is that you were
   assigning the functions to the
   checkboxes inside the `paginateIt`
   function so each time it was run (on
   each click to a checkbox) you were
   adding additional click event to
   each checkbox.. after a few clicks
   the browser would start freezing ..
2. so i moved the click event to be
   assigned outside the `paginateIt`
   function (only once) you do not need
   to identify each group if checkboxes
   since the action that is being
   performed is the same in all cases
   ... I changed all hidden classes to
   a single one named hidden.
3. the `$('#content').children().filter`
   would always return all the elements
   so i changed it to `$('#content div
   div').filter`, but this is specific
   to the current implementation of
   your html. This was happening
   because the `children()` are the
   immediate children of the selector
   and since you have a div wrapped
   around each one final element (the
   one which is either hidden or not)
   it would always return the max
   number ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function paginateIt(){
 //how much items per page to show
 var show_per_page = 5; 
 //getting the amount of elements inside content div
 var number_of_items = $('#content div div').filter(":not(.hidden)").size();

 //calculate the number of pages we are going to have
 var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items/show_per_page);

 //set the value of our hidden input fields
 $('#current_page').val(0);
 $('#show_per_page').val(show_per_page);

 //now when we got all we need for the navigation let's make it '

 /* 
 what are we going to have in the navigation?
  - link to previous page
  - links to specific pages
  - link to next page
 */
 var navigation_html = '<a class="previous_link" href="javascript:previous();">Prev</a>';
 var current_link = 0;
 while(number_of_pages > current_link){
  navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(' + current_link +')" longdesc="' + current_link +'">'+ (current_link + 1) +'</a>';
  current_link++;
 }
 navigation_html += '<a class="next_link" href="javascript:next();">Next</a>';

 $('#page_navigation').html(navigation_html);

 //add active_page class to the first page link
 $('#page_navigation .page_link:first').addClass('active_page');

 //hide all the elements inside content div
 $('#content div div').filter(":not(.hidden)").css('display', 'none');

 //and show the first n (show_per_page) elements
 $('#content div div').filter(":not(.hidden)").slice(0, show_per_page).css('display', 'block');
}


 $("input:checkbox").click(function() {

   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#events div."+$(this).attr('id')).removeClass('hidden');
    $("#events div").not(".hidden").show();
   } else {
    $("#events div."+$(this).attr('id')).addClass('hidden');
    $("#events div."+$(this).attr('id')).hide();
   }
   paginateIt();
  });

 paginateIt();

});

function previous(){

 new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) - 1;
 //if there is an item before the current active link run the function
 if($('.active_page').prev('.page_link').length==true){
  go_to_page(new_page);
 }

}

function next(){
 new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) + 1;
 //if there is an item after the current active link run the function
 if($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length==true){
  go_to_page(new_page);
 }

}
function go_to_page(page_num){
 //get the number of items shown per page
 var show_per_page = parseInt($('#show_per_page').val());

 //get the element number where to start the slice from
 start_from = page_num * show_per_page;

 //get the element number where to end the slice
 end_on = start_from + show_per_page;

 //hide all children elements of content div, get specific items and show them
 $('#content div div').filter(":not(.hidden)").css('display', 'none').slice(start_from, end_on).css('display', 'block');

 /*get the page link that has longdesc attribute of the current page and add active_page class to it
 and remove that class from previously active page link*/
 $('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num +']').addClass('active_page').siblings('.active_page').removeClass('active_page');

 //update the current page input field
 $('#current_page').val(page_num);
}
```

Comment: Ok, i am sorry for that ... some parts (where you create the navigation tags) were eaten out due to the actual tags being parsed by StackOverflow ..

(I have edited the original answer)

take that part now and it should be fine

Comment: Tried the above script and the pagination works! but when filtering for example the colors, if I uncheck just the colors blue and green and leave on black it displays 2 results when It should display a total of 5(all the black colors). I'm guessing it is just filtering for the page and not displaying as a block for the other items. Is there a solution to this problem? - Here is the updated script -> http://jsbin.com/ekexe

Comment: there were 3 places in the code were i had not changed the ("#content").children().filter to ("#content div div").filter

(Updated now)

Comment: Keep in mind that the logic of your code is currently dealign with each filter on its own (it does not combine them). For example if you unselect all colors it will show 0 items, but if then you unselect and then re-select the automotive filter it will display all automotive items even though their color is supposed to be hidden)

Comment: that worked great, thanks. Interesting point about the filters, I did not realize. If you have any suggestions on making it better structured, that would be great, Thanks again for the help.

Comment: glad i could help. In regard to the filters, do you want them to work at the same time ? Depends on the logic you want  .. 
You want the 3 type of filters to work as AND (something must meet all 3 filters criteria to work) or OR (something must meet at least one)